# Problems with wikitude library to make AR on android

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, wikitude

Hey guys i am developing and AR application and since wikitude and Layar are the ones only in my knowledge i am using their libraries being wikitude this time.

The following are the issues which i am facing :-

- When i am on gps and out on streets only then does it shows my poi else it doesnt and i have both the permissions added in manifest and internet permission also
- When i add title to poi by  poi.setName("Title"); i am not shown the poi
- Same goes with the description
- I have got the key also and added that in wikitudeArIntent but still whenever i run the application the text "Wikitude" always come on the bottom left corner in the camera view
- Is there any other open source library for making AR applications for android ?? is there a better to do all this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mixare is an augmented reality library, free and open source
www.mixare.org
www.bango29.com/go/blog/2010/mixare-augmented-reality-tutorial

Comment: Mixare is under GPL license, which makes it bad choice for commercial projects